# what's the difference if a number with parenthesis or without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

[image]

the type of (8) and 8 are both numbers, but when called toString() method, (8) success but 8 failed, why?

Comment: What do you get when you do `"8".toString(2)`?

Comment: when you cover a number with parenthesis then that would become an expression.

Comment: give a space after 8 otherwise it will be treated as floating point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between having `8` and `(8)` is, the former is a plain number and the latter is a **JavaScript Expression**. The problem with the Exception is, the way you have written:

```
8.toString(2);
```

Here, the `8.` is treated as a floating point or decimal, which causes the syntax error. Since it takes it as a decimal, giving a decimal yields the right result:

```
» 8.0.toString(2);
« "1000"
```

[image]

Comment: `8` is an expression as well.

Comment: @georg But it is treated as floating point.

Answer (score 2):

```
8.toString() // Won't work
```

Here `.` is treated as a floating point number representation. So if you want to convert a non floating point number into string just give a space after the number

```
8 .toString(); // Will work
```

And if it a floating point number then you can call `toString` directly

```
8.2.toString(); // Will work even it doesn't have the space
8..toString(); // Will also work
```

But I would recommend you to use parenthesis for code readability.

And a number wrapped in parenthesis is an expression.